# Where am I supposed to reimplement QApplication::notify function?

Tags: c++, qt

Where am I supposed to reimplement QApplication::notify function? What I mean is, which class? One of my own classes or subclass some of Qt's class and do it there? I need this because I'm getting the following error while downloading file from a server(small files are downloaded ok, but large ones cause this msg):

> Qt has caught an exception thrown from an event handler. Throwing
>   exceptions from an event handler is not supported in Qt. You must
>   reimplement QApplication::notify() and catch all exceptions there.

Comment: Hi, see if this helps: http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/17731.

There, they subclass `QtApplication` and reimplement the `notify` method in `SafeApplication`.

Comment: #AdriC.S. Hi, I'm not sure if that's the case but I'll give it a go.

Comment: Are you sure you want to throw exceptions from event handler. How are you going to handle them?

Comment: @Lol4t0 It's a slightly misleading error, what happens is an exception is thrown in a slot, which propagates up the stack until it hits Qt's event queue processor - and it's that which displays the error.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just subclass `QApplication` and in your `notify(..)` method do something like this:

```
try {
    return QApplication::notify( receiver, event );
} catch ( std::exception& e ) {
    showAngryDialog( e );
    return false;
}
```

Then use it in your main function instead of `QApplication`.

Comment: #cmannett85 hi, this indeed did the trick. The 'e' is a std::bad_alloc. Any idea what the hell? Do I need to increase heap?

Comment: @user336359 Either you're trying to allocate an absurd amount of memory, or you're running Qt on a low-resource/embedded system.

Comment: it's most likely the former. What I'm doing is I'm downloading file, and I have connected signal to slot: QNetworkReply* reply = network_access_manager_->get(request);
    connect(reply,SIGNAL(downloadProgress(qint64,qint64)),parent_->getProgressBar(),SLOT(downloadProgress(qint64,qint64)));

Comment: #cmannett85 not only that but, download is successfull when files are small, but when there are 1GB download stops in 73%, if I don't connect those slots, or program crashes with bad_alloc if I connect those slots.

Comment: @user336359 Well if you get stuck post another question.

Answer (score 7):

As said before create you own application object that inherits from QtApplication and redefine 'notify'. It is the way to go. However be very sure to use this constructor:

```
MyApplication::MyApplication(int &argc, char *argv[]);
```

Setting argc as reference with '&' is important as it avoids a crash on some platforms.

The full procedure is described here: http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/17731

My own implementation:

```
class MyApplication : public QApplication
{
public:
    MyApplication(int &argc, char ** argv);
    // ~MyApplication();
private:
    bool notify(QObject *receiver_, QEvent *event_);
};
```

(The crash described above happened on Ubuntu 13.10 64bits but was not present on version 12.04 64 bits.)

Comment: That comment about using the `int &` really helped me out.  My application kept crashing until I did that.